# Simple way to combine EACH element of two complex lists in R?

Tags: r, list, lapply, nested-lists

Say I have two lists, each containing multiple sub-elements:

```
l1 <- list(c(1933:1935),c(1950:1954), c(2012:2013))  #groups of years
l2 <- list(c(19:21),c(19:24),c(22:26))               #groups of plot numbers
```

I want to create a new list (we'll call it "`l3`")  of sublists in which:

- each element of my new list (`l3`) corresponds to each element of `l1`

  - in this case, `l1` has 3 elements (each containing variable numbers of years), so I want `l3` to have 3 main elements as well.
- within a given element of `l3`, I want each year listed in the corresponding element from `l1` to contain all `l2` elements *within* the same element of `l2`

The result would look like:

```
> l3
[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] 19 20 21

[[1]]
[[2]]
[1] 19 20 21

[[1]]
[[3]]
[1] 19 20 21

[[2]]
[[1]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]]
[[2]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]]
[[3]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]]
[[4]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[3]]
[[1]]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26

[[3]]
[[2]]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` with `lapply`, in the map function, for each sublist of `l1` return the `number` vector for each year:

```
Map(function(years, numbers) lapply(years, function(x) numbers), l1, l2)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 19 20 21

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 19 20 21

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 19 20 21


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24

[[2]][[5]]
[1] 19 20 21 22 23 24


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 22 23 24 25 26
```

Or another option, use `rep`:

```
Map(function(n, v) rep(list(v), n), lengths(l1), l2)
```